# How to NOT delete completed tasks in Google Tasks

Tags: google-tasks

For years of use, Google Tasks put a checkmark by completed tasks.  You could, whenever you wished, delete all completed tasks.

But starting a few days ago, any completed task is immediately whisked away.

Is there any way to go back to the long-standing procedure?